# Filtering listview data by column name using combobox and textbox

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to filter my data in list view by allowing the user to select a column name and search for the data using the textbox.

Here is my code

```
 Private Sub Search()

    lviStock.Items.Clear()
    Dim item As New ListViewItem()
    Dim _isFound As Boolean = False

    Dim colName() As String = {"MedicineID", "Medicine_Name"}

    Dim strSqlSearch As String = "SELECT MedicineID, Medicine_Name " &
                                    "FROM medicine " &
                                    "WHERE " & colName(cboColumns.SelectedIndex) & "' LIKE '" & txtSearchCriteria.Text & "%'"

    Using myConn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; userid = root; password = root; database= database")
        Using myComm As New MySqlCommand()
            With myComm
                .Connection = myConn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = strSqlSearch
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@valueName", txtSearchCriteria.Text)
            End With
            Try
                myConn.Open()
                Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader = myComm.ExecuteReader()

                While myReader.Read()
                    _isFound = True
                    item = lviClientlist.Items.Add(myReader("MedicineID").ToString)
                    item.SubItems.Add(myReader("Medicine_Name").ToString)

                End While

                If Not _isFound Then
                    MsgBox("No results found.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Stock System")
                End If

            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Stock System")
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Now I keep getting an error that says "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

With the part highlighted

```
Dim strSqlSearch As String = "SELECT MedicineID, Medicine_Name " &
                                    "FROM medicine " &
                                    "WHERE " & colName(cboColumns.SelectedIndex) & "' LIKE '" & txtSearchCriteria.Text & "%'"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: One way to fix it is to use a DataGridView with a DataView.  Rather than running a new query, all you would have to do is set the RowFilter property. If cboColumns has nothing selected it will be -1 which is out of bounds, or `cboColumns.SelectedIndex` may be larger than the array.  Debug your code and check

Comment: What if your combo has no item selected? In that case the SelectedIndex property is -1 causing the first error in this code.

Comment: @Plutonix I'm sorry I'm a bit of a beginner but is there any way to go about doing that using listview or only datagridview. If you can please explain it a bit further as well. Thank you.

Comment: The first error is that combobox as Steve said. Validate the user data *before* you call this method. The next error will be about @value.  The LV is not a grid - it just looks like one (sometimes).  If this an app relying on a database and queries, switching to a DGV will save lots of code.